# Как найти индексы элементов одного списка внутри другого?

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть 2 списка.

Вот пример:

```
ls1 = [12,3,1,4,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1]
ls2 = [3,4,5]
```

И в первом и во втором списке элементы не уникальные - они могу повторяться.

Мне надо найти пересечение двух списков (учитывая порядок элементов) и вернуть индексы элементов пересечения в первом списке.
Должно быть что-то вроде:

```
[5, 7]
```

где

`5` - начальный индекс пересечения в первом списке

`7` - последний индекс пересечения в первом списке

Как я могу это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Брать в цикле срез `[i:i+len(ls2)]` в первом списке и сравнивать его со вторым. Если одинаково, то искомые индексы будут `[i:i+len(ls2)-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
length = len(ls1)
for i in range(len(ls2) - length+1):
    if ls2[i:i+length] == ls1:
        print(i, i+length-1)
```

Вот возможное решение
Спасибо, @Эникейщик

Comment: только вы перепутали местами ls1 и ls2.